How can I see the light emitted by a emissions plane that is parallel to the viewport in Blender's Eevee renderer?
By blender 4.2  eevee
When the plane is parallel to the viewport, I can't see the light emitted by the plane illuminating the monkey


using the Light Probe ↓


You can use a Light Probe > Volume to get the reflections but it won't be as convenient as the ligth area trick

Thank you !  but I can't see the light emitted by the plane using the Light Probe. I don't know why, maybe my settings are wrong...

after you've created the light probe > Volume, go into the Render panel > Indirect Lighting > Bake Indirect Lighting

"That's useful! I found this setting, but in Eevee 4.2, the setting you mentioned seems to have been moved. Now it's under Light Probe Volume ⇒ Data ⇒ Bake Light." I can finally see the light emitted by the plane now!"

in 4.2 you can also go into the Render panel and activate the Raytracing option, see if it works fine

You can’t. EEVEE’s response to emissive materials is all screen space stuff, so anything not visible will not affect the effects. I suggest you instead fake it using a plane light, lined up with and the same size as the plane mesh, and just a millimeter or so above it.

Thanks, that really cleared things up for me, it was really helpful! I thought it was just me not setting it up right.

@user208244 if this answer is correct, mark it as such

By default an emission shader won't emit light in Eevee. But since 4.2 you can activate the Raytracing option in the Render panel. You can also create a Light Probe > Volume then, before 4.2 go into the Render panel > Indirect Lighting and Bake Indirect Lighting. Since 4.2, select the light probe and in the Data panel > Bake > Bake Light Cache.
Or as suggested by TheLabCat, create an area light.
